# LXE-HX2i decrease battery voltage, step-down converter

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, step-down

[image: LXE-HX2i battery]

Hello,
I got this battery and I want to decrease it's voltage output. Can I just use cheap step-down converter with LM2596 onboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop to 3.3V is ok by the 3.3V version of LM2596. The 5V version needs input=7V or more. It's possible that your circuit does not work when the battery is only half full or nearly empty. See the specs from the original datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf